# iOS My application.xcodeproj causes and display red text, Then I unable to open project?

Tags: ios, xcode, file, project

I have facing this issue when I was changing project name and copying my project from one mac to another. There are some red texts indicate the missing files from the project source codes(But I have all files in Project folder) I have used cocoapods in this project. How to avoid these?

Here I have shown my project screen shot.

[image]

Comment: check you target and choose correct one if you have multiple targets.

Answer (score 0):

As per your description... you must be having some issue in your project.pbxproj file. Please check that file. Common issue happens in that file when you try to merge different branches having conflicts in project structure.

Comment: I have checked that project.pbxproj file there was no issue on that file. I have unzip my old back file that also shows same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There could be different reasons of this:
It may happen because the xcode is open and the source folder is not available.
It may happen when source path is not found in your system and xcode shows that.

For resolving this, quiet xcode and reopen your source from .xcodeproj again, will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the file, then on the far top right of Xcode look under **Identity and Type** Check and see if the path to the file is correct. In my case is was not so I had to click on the small folder icon (not the arrow icon) and select the folder in finder.